# .tgz not extracting properly

Tags: tar

I've just received some files file(s).tgz... I've tried tar -xvzf file.tgz... However I'm getting error "Attempt to write to an empty file"... Am I missing something... The folder directory system has been made but all the directories are empty...

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot find the string "Attempt to write to an empty file" in the source code for tar or gzip.  Is that the exact error message, or are you rephrasing?

Comment: Exact message... I'm on MacOX... bsdtar 2.6.2 - libarchive 2.6.2

Answer (score 12):

A similar issue is encountered at http://code.google.com/p/libarchive/issues/detail?id=3

It looks like a bug in BSD tar, which is the default tar on FreeBSD, Mac OS X, and possibly other systems.

Easiest workaround is probably to extract with GNU tar. Just run "gnutar" instead of "tar" if you're on OS X. On FreeBSD you may need to install gnutar from ports.

Comment: I was using BSD tar... and I needed to use GNU tar.... On Mac OSX use "gnutar -xvzf"... Many thanks...

Comment: Nice. On Mac OS X, I did the following:

brew install gnu-tar

Then just made sure my path was updated to include that tar first, then it works fine.

Comment: sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/gnu-tar/libexec/gnubin/tar /usr/bin/gnutar

Comment: `brew install gnu-tar` then `gtar zxvf ...` worked for me.